# Files were not listed with git status and got lost after a commit

Tags: linux, git, github

I lost files from my local repo. by "mistake" after using git. Am trying to understand that mistake and undo it if possible. what I did sequentially is:

```
git status
git add -A
git commit -m "some message"
git push origin master
```

The weird part is that I had some new files (since the last commit) that did not get committed and pushed, and now do not exist on my local repo.

Looking more into it, **I saw that my git status did not list these files in the first place. These are the files that I lost. Why would that happen ? and is there a way to get them back ?**

I have git version `1.8.3.1`

Comment: If the files were already gone *before* your `git status`, there's little we can do to guess what the problem is. Can you try to give some history of previous operations?

Comment: None of those commands would cause any files to be deleted. Whatever happened wasn't caused by what you listed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add the files to git at any point, it's unlikely you can recover them using git. You can see if they are in your repository by this handy "one-liner"

```
alias gitobjects="git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %
       │ (objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | sed -n 's/^blob //p' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 | c
       │ ut -c 1-12,41- | numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest"
gitobjects | grep "myfile"
```